# Select row of UIPicker dynamically

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a question about the following code: the UserLoad array contains a series of users with a Username field, I want to select the uipicker line based on the username,
the following code does not find the text inside the array ending up in the else

```
func selectPicker(withText text: String) {
        print("Testo: \(text)")
        if let index = self.UserLoad.firstIndex(where: { $0.Username == text }) {
            print("Indice di riga: \(index)")
            RisorseUmaneUIPicker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        }
        else {
            print("text not found")
        }
    }
```

Comment: start property name with a lower case letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try search with `lowercased`

```
let sub = text.lowercased() 
if let index = self.userLoad.firstIndex(where: { $0.username.lowercased() == sub } {}
```

if not works then your array doesn't contain that user